# How to properly mapping object in fluent nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm

Its first time when I'm using ORM.

Here is my code:

```
public class EwidencjonowanaRzeczMap : ClassMap<EwidencjonowanaRzecz>
        {
            public EwidencjonowanaRzeczMap()
            {
                Id(c => c.Id);
                References(m => m.WagaRef);
            }
        }

        public class WagaMap : ClassMap<Waga>
        {
            public WagaMap()
            {
                Id(m => m.Id);
                Map(m => m.WagaPrzedmiotu);
                HasMany(m => m.ListaRzeczy).Inverse().Cascade.All();
            }
        }

public class EwidencjonowanaRzecz
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Waga WagaRef { get; set; }
    }

    public class Waga
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual String WagaPrzedmiotu { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<EwidencjonowanaRzecz> ListaRzeczy { get; set; } 
        public Waga()
        {
            ListaRzeczy = new List<EwidencjonowanaRzecz>();
        }
    }
```

Here is my function to select records:

```
public IList<T> SelectAllFromTable<T>()
        {
            IList<T> czyDanePoprawne = null;
            try
            {
                _sesja = NHibernateHelper.CreateSessionFactory().OpenSession();
                using (_sesja.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    czyDanePoprawne = _sesja.CreateCriteria(typeof(T)).List<T>();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                CzyNieWystapilyBledy = true;
            }
            return czyDanePoprawne;
        }
```

Tables:

`ewidencjonowanarzecz [ Id - PK , IdWagi - FK (Waga.Id)]`

`waga [ Id - PK , WagaPrzedmiotu ]`

Every type Id's - INT(3) 
WagaPrzedmiotu is VARCHAR(10)

How to read to list these 2 fields?:

`Id` (ewidencjonowanarzecz) and  `WagaPrzedmiotu` (waga)

In my mapping:

`EwidencjaList = ModelBazy.SelectAllFromTable<EwidencjonowanaRzecz>();`

is empty.

What is wrong with my mapping?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the table record you can try this :

```
_sesja = NHibernateHelper.CreateSessionFactory().OpenSession();
var tabledata = _sesja.CreateQuery("from EwidencjonowanaRzecz").List<EwidencjonowanaRzecz>();
```

If you want to check whether if it fetches the values, try this

```
string value = tabledata.WagaPrzedmiotu;
```

Comment: i generated all tables by fluent nhibernate and its work  ;) thx for answer